# What does illegal character in numeric field error concern for Cobol using Unix system?

Tags: average, numeric, cobol

How to solve the error:

Execution error : file 'prog3.int'

error code: 163, pc=177, call=1, seg=0

163     Illegal character in numeric field

```
            IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. prog3.      


    ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
    Input-output Section.
    File-Control.
            select input-file assign to 
              "/home1/c/a/acsi203/realestate.dat".
            select output-file assign to "prog3out.dat"
               organization is line sequential.


    DATA    DIVISION.
    File    Section.
    FD      Input-File.
    01      INPUT-REC.
            02 PropertyAddress  pic x(27).
            02 City             pic a(15).
            02 Zip              pic 9(5).
            02 State            pic a(2).
            02 Bedrooms         pic 9.
            02 Bathrooms        pic 9.
            02 SqFt             pic 9(4).
            02 PropertyType     pic x(8).
            02 SaleDayofWeek    pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleMonth        pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleDay          pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleHour         pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleMinute       pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleSecond       pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 TimeZone         pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(1).
            02 SaleYear         pic 9(4).
            02 SalePrice        pic 9(6).
            02 Filler           pic x(18).

    FD  OUTPUT-FILE.
    01  OUTPUT-REC              pic x(114).


    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 REPORT-HEADER.

            02 Filler           pic x(27) value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(66) value 
              "Sacramento Area Real Estate Transactions-MM/DD/YYYY".
            02 Filler           pic x(61) value spaces.
    01 RECORDS-PROCESSED.
            02 Filler           pic x(28) value 
                    "Number Of Records Processed:".
            02 num-recs         pic 9(4)   value 0.
            02 Filler           pic x(15) value spaces.
    01 AVERAGE-PROCESSED.
            02 Filler           pic x(9)  value
                    "Average: ".
            02 num-nonzero      pic 9(4) value 0.
            02 Filler           pic x(45) value spaces.
            02 BedroomAverage-out pic x(1).
            02 Filler           pic x(10) value spaces.
            02 BathroomAverage-out pic x(1).
            02 Filler           pic x(18) value spaces.
            02 SqFtAverage-out  pic $ZZ,ZZ9.99.
            02 Filler           pic x(4) value spaces.
            02 SalePriceAverage-out pic $ZZ,ZZ9.99.
    01 END-OF-REPORT.
            02 Filler           pic x(13) value
                    "End Of Report".

    01 COLUMN-HEADER.
            02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(16) value "Property Address".
            02 Filler           pic x(10) value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(4)  value "City".
            02 Filler           pic x(10) value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(5)  value "Zip".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(5)  value "State".
            02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(8)  value "Bedrooms".
            02 Filler           pic x(3)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(9)  value "Bathrooms".
            02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(4) value "SqFt".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(13) value "Property Type".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(13) value "SaleDayOfWeek".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(9)  value "SaleMonth".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(7)  value "SaleDay".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(8)  value "SaleHour".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(10) value "SaleMinute".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(10)  value "SaleSecond".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(8)  value "TimeZone".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(8)  value "SaleYear".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(9)  value "SalePrice".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(12) value "PricePerSqFt".
            02 Filler           pic x(1)  value spaces.
            02 Filler           pic x(5)  value "Taxes".

    01 INFO-LINE.
            02 Filler           pic x(3)  value spaces.
            02 PropertyAddress-out    pic x(20).
            02 Filler           pic x(2)  value spaces.
            02 City-out         pic a(15).
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 Zip-out          pic 9(6).
            02 Filler           pic x(2) value spaces.
            02 State-out        pic a(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(7) value spaces.
            02 Bedrooms-out     pic 9.
            02 Filler           pic x(10) value spaces.
            02 Bathrooms-out    pic 9.
            02 Filler           pic x(2) value spaces.
            02 SqFt-out         pic 9(4).
            02 Filler           pic x(9)  value spaces.
            02 PropertyType-out pic x(8).
            02 Filler           pic x(5) values spaces.
            02 SaleDayOfWeek-out pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(5).
            02 SaleMonth-out    pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(5) value spaces.
            02 SaleDay-out      pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 SaleHour-out     pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 SaleMinute-out   pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 SaleSecond-out   pic 9(2).
            02 Filler           pic x(2) value spaces.
            02 TimeZone-out     pic a(3).
            02 Filler           pic x(1) value spaces.
            02 SaleYear-out     pic 9(4).
            02 Filler           pic x(5) value spaces.
            02 SalePrice-out    pic 9(6).
            02 Filler           pic x(4) value spaces.
            02 PriceSqFtT-out   pic $ZZ,ZZ9.99.
            02 Filler           pic x(2) value spaces.
            02 Taxes-out        pic 9(5).     

    01 TEMP-VAR.
            02 PriceSqFtT       pic 9(5) value zero.
            02 PriceSqFtAccum   pic 9(6) value zero.
            02 BedroomAverage     pic 9(1) value zero.
            02 BathroomAverage    pic 9(1) value zero.
            02 SqFtAverage        pic 9(6) value zero.
            02 SalePriceAverage   pic 9(7) value zero.
            02 Taxes            pic 9(6) value zero.
    01 eof-flag                 pic x(3) value "No".

    PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    0000-MAIN-LOGIC.
            Perform 1000-init.
            Perform 2000-main-loop until eof-flag = "yes".
            Perform 3000-finish.
            stop run.

    1000-init.
            open input input-file
            output output-file.

            write output-rec from Report-Header.
            write output-rec from Column-Header.
            Read input-file at end move "yes" to eof-flag.

    2000-main-loop.
            DISPLAY INPUT-REC.
            move PropertyAddress to PropertyAddress-out.
            move City to City-out.
            move Zip to Zip-out.
            move State to State-out.
            move Bedrooms to Bedrooms-out.
            move Bathrooms to Bathrooms-out.
            move PropertyType to PropertyType-out.
            move SalePrice to SalePrice-out.
            move SaleDayOfWeek to SaleDayOfWeek-out.
            move SaleMonth to SaleMonth-out.
            move SaleDay to SaleDay-out.
            move SaleHour to SaleHour-out.
            move SaleMinute to SaleMinute-out.
            move TimeZone to TimeZone-out.
            move SaleYear to SaleYear-out.
            move SalePrice to SalePrice-out.
            divide SalePrice by sqFt giving PriceSqFtT.
            Add PriceSqFtT to  PriceSqFtAccum.
            Move PriceSqFtT to PriceSqFtT-out.
            add 1 to num-recs.
            if sqft not = 0 and Bedrooms not = 0 and 
             Bathrooms not = 0 and SalePrice not = 0
             add 1 to num-nonzero.
            IF city EQUALS "SACRAMENTO" and Bedrooms EQUALS 2

               compute Taxes = salePrice * 7.5.
            IF city EQUALS "SACRAMENTO" THEN 
               MULTIPLY salePrice by 6 giving Taxes.
            IF city NOT EQUAL "SACRAMENTO"
               MULTIPLY salePrice  by 6 giving Taxes.
        move Taxes to Taxes-out.
            divide Bedrooms by num-nonzero giving BedroomAverage.
            divide Bathrooms by num-nonzero giving BathroomAverage.
            divide SqFt by num-nonzero giving SqFtAverage.
            divide SalePrice by num-nonzero giving SalePriceAverage.
            move Bedrooms to BedroomAverage-out.
            move Bathrooms to BathroomAverage-out.
            move SqFt to SqFtAverage-out.
            move SalePrice to SalePriceAverage-out.
            write output-rec from info-line.
            read input-file at end move "yes" to eof-flag.

    3000-finish.
            write output-rec from Records-processed

            write output-rec from AVERAGE-PROCESSED
            write output-rec from END-OF-REPORT
            close input-file output-file.
```

**************THE FOLLOWING IS THE OUTPUT PRODUCED WITH THE ERROR***************

1122 WILD POPPY CT         GALT           95632 CA 321406 Resident Wed May 21 02:00:00 EDT 2008 178760 38287789121294715

4520 BOMARK WAY            SACRAMENTO     95842 CA 421943 Multi-Fa Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008 179580 38665724121358576

4520 BOBAY PKWAY           SACRAMENTO     95842 CA k2194j Multi-Fa Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008 179580 38665724121358576

Execution error : file 'prog3.int'
error code: 163, pc=189, call=1, seg=0
163     Illegal character in numeric field

**************END OF OUTPUT WITH EXECUTION ERROR***************************

I am creating a Cobol program that computes the lines of information and averages on following input file. However, I keep getting the 'illegal character in numeric field' error and I can't understand why. I am using Unix system to compile and run this. Please help. Very new to this!

Input File:  /home1/c/a/acsi203/realestate.dat

Columns         Type            Data

-------         ----            ---------

1-27       Alphanumeric          Property Address

28-42      Alphabetic           City

43-47      Numeric               Zip

48-49      Alphabetic           State

50         Numeric               Number of Bedrooms

51         Numeric               Number of Bathrooms

52-55      Numeric               Square Feet

56-63      Alphanumeric          Property Type

64-66      Alhpabetic           Sale Day of Week

68-70      Alphabetic           Sale Month

72-73      Numeric               Sale Day

75-76      Numeric               Sale Hour

78-79      Numeric               Sale Minute

81-82      Numeric               Sale Second

84-86      Alphabetic           Time Zone

88-91      Numeric               Sale Year

92-97      Numeric               Sale Price

98-105     Numeric               Property Latitude (2 places to left)

106-114    Numeric               Property Longitude(2 places to left)

Comment: Which data can I present you with sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing FILLER PIC X after the Zip. You need to go through with the actual data and make sure that all the fields line up with your definitions. Don't rely on the written definitions you included. The data is what it really is. Now that comments aren't compressing spaces, the long and lat can go back, but note that they are not numeric-edited fields as you previously described.

---

You are using a Micro Focus COBOL.

Here, http://supportline.microfocus.com/kbdocs/KBdo4363.HTM, is a description of your error code.

Here, is the relevant quote for your problem:

```
Every value you attempt to move to a numeric or numeric edited field is checked to ensure that it is numeric.
```

You have now edited your question to show that your Longitude and Latitude fields are `numeric-edited` fields. That means they are not numeric. So when you attempt:

```
        move PropertyLatitude to PropertyLatitude-out.
```

You will get that message.

Of course, this presumes that your definition of that field matches the data.

Why are you moving those two fields to two two-digit numeric fields in your report?

Comment: The point is to assume that records that do not meet these conditions should be written to a separate error file with messages for each error found in the record. Validation paragraph should use condition names to implement validation flags.

Comment: Does this help a little bit? I must change the longitude and latitude to: 9V99?

Comment: If your definitions are correct (ZZ,ZZ9.99) change them in the report line to PIC X(9).

Comment: Any luck with pasting the three lines of data? And please update the question again with the current code.

Comment: Execution error : file 'prog3.int'

error code: 163, pc=177, call=1, seg=0

163 Illegal character in numeric field

Comment: We. Need. To. See. The. Data. Please.

Comment: I do not have access to realestate.dat from "/home1/c/a/acsi203/realestate.dat".

Comment: I am only given Columns Type Data such as

------- ---- ---------

1-27 Alphanumeric Property Addres

Comment: So what data do you have access to which you are running your program on? Add a line DISPLAY INPUT-REC as the first line in your 2000-main-loop. Compile and run again. Paste the last three lines (or all of them if less than three) that are shown in your output.

Comment: 3526 HIGH ST               SACRAMENTO     95838CA210836ResidentWed May 21 01:00:                                                             00 EDT 200805922238631913121434879

Comment: This is what is printed ^^

Comment: It doesn't match your layout :-)

Comment: For instance, there are only 97 characters. Comment out the MOVE of the longitude and latitude. They do not exist on that record.

Comment: This is very interesting!! I have removed those lines of code instead of commenting them out and get more of this output followed by the original error:

3526 HIGH ST               SACRAMENTO     95838CA210836ResidentWed May 21 01:00:00 EDT 200805922238631913121434879

51 OMAHA CT                SACRAMENTO     95823CA311167ResidentWed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 200806821238478902121431028

2796 BRANCH ST             SACRAMENTO     95815CA210796ResidentWed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 200806888038618305121443839

163     Illegal character in numeric field

Comment: Can you paste that into your question, with the current version of your code. Be careful to format the data correctly. As it is, I can't get the lines to line up, and your previous data-line seems to have contained a typo.

Comment: I tried to make it neater, however i'm quite unsure what the last bit of numbers is after the sale price is produced. I've shown it under my code.

Comment: Ha. The lack of formatting in the comments were eating multiple spaces.

Comment: If you don't have access to the file can you not code to copy record for record  to a local file ?   Do you know how many records there are ? At least the filesize so we can divide it by the record "length".

- and you could temporarily test for numeric around every move of a numeric field to default to a constant and display a message.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but I thought I should bring to your attention that the rules for taxes in your code do not make sense (see below).  The second if statement will always replace the results of the first if statement.  If this code is really producing the outcome you want, you could get the same result by replacing all 6 lines of code with one line: MULTIPLY salePrice by 6 giving Taxes.

```
        IF city EQUALS "SACRAMENTO" and Bedrooms EQUALS 2
           compute Taxes = salePrice * 7.5.
        IF city EQUALS "SACRAMENTO" THEN 
           MULTIPLY salePrice by 6 giving Taxes.
        IF city NOT EQUAL "SACRAMENTO"
           MULTIPLY salePrice  by 6 giving Taxes.
```